# Choosing Variables to a Multiple Regression Model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, pca, predictive-models

Right now, I'm trying to use some georeferenced data to predict revenue for some stores.

My data set has 21 obs (Annual Revenue for 21 stores), but I have 306 variables (Population/pop density, area, income groups, purchasing potential, and so on, for 3 different radius: 1km, 3km and 5km). Here is a print of my dataset.

[image: Dataset 1]

As I don't have a large number of observations, I cannot run a multiple linear regression, so I decided to analyze the correlation matrix of the variables and  to perform a principal component analysis and define which variable would be interesting (or maybe a linear combination). In the figure above, everything in red is 1 and in green is >.9.

[image: Correlation Matrix]

My intention is to use these variables to increment another predicition model where I have ~ 4000 variables to predict an hourly numbers of item sales, based in dummy variables for days of week, month, hollidays, distance to payment days, etc, for the 21 stores). Also I'll review that model to discard some variables, ~ 4000 maybe is a little too much and brings me a lot of problems.

Here is the R lm summary to the 4000 variables model:

Residual standard error: 498.4 on 19062 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.821, Adjusted R-squared:  0.8164 
F-statistic: 179.8 on 486 and 19062 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

As I'm quite new to statistics models, I'm not sure if I'm doing something -really- wrong, so I wanted to ask if you have any suggestions about choosing variables to my models

Thank you!

Comment: The standard approach to variable selection in linear models is a penalized regression model like a LASSO.

Comment: Your implied approach is not based on statistical principles.  For one thing you may be hurting an unsupervised learning approach (principal components) by letting it make use of the correlations with $Y$.  For your problem I'd look at variable clustering followed by principal components, or consider sparse principal components analysis.  More details are in my RMS course [notes and book](http://www.fharrell.com/p/blog-page.html).

Comment: Correct link should be https://hbiostat.org/rms

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about Regression Model Selection (Stepwise and subset model) selection
The problem in these techniques when applied directly is that they use internal measure (F-Test), which may be misleading . Your best move is to apply these techniques but by using cross validation as selection criteria , this will give you probably the best model you can apply on NEW data

Comment: Fair, but why use stepwise at all when ridge and lasso are available.

Comment: They will probably amount to the same  thing. The lasso will set most things to 0, and the forward stepwise is choosing the possible non zero values in a greedy fashion. Judging from the covariance matrix, it is likely we will be left with 1 or 2 features.